# Small query on shared view takes a long time when someone else is running a big query on the same view

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2014

Can anyone explain to me why a small query takes a long time on a shared view when someone is running a big query on the same view?

I found a solution to the problem by using Table-valued function instead.

But I'd like to understand why sharing the same view creates this problem in SQL SERVER 2014?

The TVF and View queries the same tables, but why would the TVF consistently run faster?

Here's the actual execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SylaMlQqf

Comment: What do you mean by sharing a view? And what is a view that is not shared?

Comment: One thing could be table is being locked for the reads.  If you do not care about  grabbing any records that are currently in process of being updated/deleted/inserted you can add (NOLOCK) to your queries and that could help.  (though it could be a LOT of things)

Comment: There seem to be people on this thread that are suggesting using NOLOCK. It is far more sinister than most people realize. Dirty reads can bring about really bizarre issues that are impossible to debug. You can read more about the sinister side of that hint here. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @SeanLange true, I just wanted to be clear. Also, I will not be using `nolock`

Comment: Yeah but you also shouldn't avoid using `nolock` to investigate a problem on principle alone. If you're not sure what's going on, and you suspect there might be blocking issues, running the same query with nolock is an almost instantaneous way to confirm your suspicion. As long as you don't then get lulled into that being the end of your investigation, I wouldn't simply discount it out of hand. As is hopefully clear at this point, it comes with a *ton* of important caveats. But like all features, its use has a time and a place.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot  more info we would need to go on to say anything definitively, but it sounds like your small query is being "blocked". Relational Databases use "locks" to make sure that if you read data in one state, another process can't come along and change it out from under you. It's completely possible the other query is doing something which needs to complete or roll back before you're allowed to see that resource.

As a side note, you could try adding a `with (nolock)` hint to your smaller query and see if it still takes a long time. That directive essentially bypasses most of the locks SQL usually uses to keep your query ACID-complient. I should note however that in general, that's not a great idea to leave on there as, believe it or not, those locks actually serve a number of purposes. Either way, it might be a useful investagative tool for you.

You might look up some resources on the acronym ACID which is a more general description of the topic.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

Comment: If the table is locked, then why does the TVF run fast consistently?

Comment: Again, you're not giving me much to go on here. An execution plan would be super helpful. But, for one thing, you can't do DML via a TVF, and you CAN via a view. So one might have contention the other doesn't. Or they could be getting different query plans causing one to get a more aggressive  lock the other isn't trying to acquire. These are just guesses though.

Comment: I wonder if there's a lock on the view itself when it's running. I notice when a user runs the view, I can't alter the view.

Comment: Whoops here's the actual plan that's not an image: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SylaMlQqf